# get does not get value

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

It should get text from textbox3 from form1 but it doesn't. Preview form is picturebox, I want to Load image by picureBox1.Load(url_from_textbox3_form_form1) and change form size (width = picturebox.image.with and height = same). If I paste text in visual studio editor all works fine.

Form1:

```
public string previewImageUrl
        {
            get { return textBox3.Text; }
        }

private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox3.Text != null)
            {
                previewImage frm = new previewImage();
                frm.ShowDialog(this);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("You're an idiot.", "LOL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

previewImage form:

```
public void load()
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            string url = frm.previewImageUrl;
            MessageBox.Show(url);
            try
            {
                pictureBox1.Load(url);
                this.Width = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
                this.Height = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
                MessageBox.Show(pictureBox1.Image.Height.ToString() + " ; " + pictureBox1.Image.Width.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void previewImage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(load));
            thread.Start();
        }
```

This thread is not needed. I just tried multiple methods with no effect.

Comment: please clarify better what's happening

Comment: I have the strange feeling that you are creating a new instance of Form1, never displaying it, but trying to read the contents of its textbox3. And by the way, if you define the textbox3 at design time it will never be null.

Comment: @Notoric `Form1` opens `previewImage` which creates new instance of `Form1`, without showing it, and takes `previewImageUrl`. It's not the same instance as previous `Form1`

Comment: Thank you all. Now I know what was my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you have ceated a new instance of the form1 like this:

```
 Form1 frm = new Form1();
```

So what you really is gets here is a new instance of the form1 (with a empty textBox3).
What you would have to do is to pass the value (TextBox3) into the previewImage form Or add the value as a parameter into the previewImage form.

Here is a way to do it:

1. Add a property in the previewImage form, like this:

   **Public Property imageUrl As String**
2. In the Form1 you would do like this:

   if (textBox3.Text != null)

   {

   ```
    previewImage frm = new previewImage();

    frm.imageUrl=TextBox3.Text;

    frm.ShowDialog(this);
   ```

   }